# NetBeans php/html error issue

Tags: php, html, netbeans

So I'm getting this error:

[image]

Every time I try to use php to dynamically change the value of a url in an href attribute.

```
<td>
    <a href="DeleteUser.php?email=<?php echo $userList[$i]['Email']; ?>">
        <div class="deleteButton"></div>
    </a>
</td>
```

I know this error is incorrect as I'm able to use the page fine, and there are no spaces in the url in the code (unless you count the ones inside the php section)

Is this a bug or am I doing something silly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the code, the error isn't even a PHP error.

This is simply Netbeans incorrectly assuming that the spaces in your link (ie `[space]echo[space]`) are actually spaces in the final URL string (which is incorrect HTML)